# how to play songs one by one in the folder?using WMPlayer.OCX

Tags: python

i got this code in by googling it and i have tried this code but it plays only songs which we are giving .

i need code to play all the songs in the folder,one by one until i stops.

````
import time
from win32com.client import Dispatch

songs_dir='G:\songs\My Fav'
songs = os.listdir(songs_dir)
mp = Dispatch("WMPlayer.OCX")
tune = mp.newMedia("{}\\{}".format(songs_dir,songs[2]))
mp.currentPlaylist.appendItem(tune)
mp.controls.play()
time.sleep(1)
mp.controls.playItem(tune)
print("Playing music")
a=input("Press Enter to stop playing")
mp.controls.stop()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove `input` because it pauses your script
- Use `time.duration` to wait for the song complete

Code:

```
import time
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

for file in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\MUSIC\*'):
    print(f'Playing: {file}')
    mp = Dispatch('WMPlayer.OCX')
    tune = mp.newMedia(file)
    mp.currentPlaylist.appendItem(tune)
    mp.controls.play()
    time.sleep(1)
    mp.controls.playItem(tune)
    time.sleep(int(tune.duration))
```

Comment: please tell me how to stop playing music when i needed, for this above program